# How can I send create gif back in php ?

Tags: php, image

I have one protocol that recieve id and send picture back.Now I have question how can I send just create .gif ?? Here please take a look to my code

```
if($id!="")
    {
        ........

        $ext = substr( $picturename, strrpos($picturename, '.')+1 );
        switch($ext)
        {
            case 'jpg':
                $ext = 'jpeg';
                break;
            case 'jpeg':
                $ext = 'jpeg';
                break;
            case 'png':
                $ext = 'png';
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $ext = 'gif';
                break;
        }

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: image/'.$ext);

        $file = "./images/".$picturename;
        readfile($file);
            //this work 

    }
    else
    {
        // Create a 1x1 image
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
        $trans = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
        // Make the background transparent
        imagecolortransparent($im, $trans);

        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        //How can I send .gif back with header ??
    }
```

Comment: sry everyone , I will accept answer when my co-programmer already done ajax code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multiple headers and output an image in the same manner. Attached is the code to generate a 1x1 pixel.

```
....
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
// output a 1x1 pixel
echo base64_decode("R0lGODdhAQABAIAAAPxqbAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=");
```

Comment: and AJAX can get echo and generate gif ?

Answer (score 0):

Just output `imagegif($im);`. Setting the `403` header doesn't do anything special, so you can output the image and that's what will be received.

Comment: Just add imagegif($im); after header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); ? Is ajax at client will recieve header 403 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to dynamically include anything in the image (like text for example) you could just have a default 1x1 image that you return instead of using imagecreate function...?

As far as the 403 header, though, I'm not sure if browsers will probably display an image if it thinks it was an error response from the server - so you might get broken images.